# Defined Commands in LyX

Tags: lyx

How can I use my defined commands in LyX? I have seen that this can be done in math mode but I have found no way to do it globally.

Comment: What commands? Are you talking about a number of `\newcommand`s that you have in your LaTeX preamble?

Comment: @Werner Yes that's right.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4737/lyx-customized-view-of-command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most fundamental way you can include `\newcommand`s you have in your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble is to use an ERT (Insert > TeX Code or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>):

[image]

With you preamble containing (say)

```
\newcommand{\quadratic}{ax^2 + bx + c}
```

the output resembles

[image]

Within math mode (Insert > Math), typing backslash `\` automatically initiates an ERT.

Comment: This works generally not in math mode only doesn't it?

Comment: @Adam: This works generally, yes. In math mode the use of ``\`` automatically assumes an ERT. Outside of math mode, a ``\`` is converted to `\textbackslash`.

Comment: Thank you! One last thing...Is there live preview for defined commands as when you write equations?

Comment: @Adam: Not natively, as you can technically have arbitrary content within a `\newcommand`, which doesn't have an HTML visual equivalent within the LyX display. You'll have to view the output - Ctrl+R - to see the rendered interpretation.

Comment: @Adam you might be interested in LyX's "math macros". See Help > Math and go to the section User-defined Commands > Math Macros.

Comment: @scottkosty: I'll add some discussion on that to this answer.

Comment: @scottkosty I have already seen them but I didn't use them. I will though. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I think Layouts and Modules is something Adam is interested in. He, as  Iunderstand, asked about non-math commands.

Comment: @Adam Note that while you can't preview all general \newcommands, you can preview basically everything you'd encounter in practice (everything other than large-scale formatting things, I think) by turning on Live Preview. If you're doing something other than Math Mode, you can make an ERT box and then right-click > Wrap in Preview to see it in your LyX file as you edit.